# generated sign out button dont work properly in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a plugin for wordpress and I used below code for crating a sign out button.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a id="btn_signout" name="btn_signout" href="<?php
     if(isset($_POST["btn_signout"])){
        wp_loginout();
     }                         
     echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Logout">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

when I login with a user and then sign out from the site and trying to login with the second user, a message appears that ask do you really want to sign out from the site?ph

Comment: how do you know you really signout ? :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're mistaking the correct use of the functions here: [`wp_loginout()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout) automatically generates and parses a logout anchor link if you're logged in and a login anchor link if your are logged out, while [`wp_logout_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url) simply returns the URL for the logout.

You can have 2 ways to sort this, either use

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <?php wp_loginout(); ?>
</div>
```

Which simply outputs a Login/Logout link already, or if you want only a logout link you can check first if the user is logged in and thereafter, print your custom anchor link:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <?php if(is_user_logged_in()): ?>
    <a id="btn_signout" name="btn_signout" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Logout">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
    </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Remember, the Wordpress Codex is your friend :)